# How preserve the dynamic content in a page?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I have an app for windows store, in one page I add content dynamically, when I navigate to the next page and come back, the dynamic content disappears.

How preserve the dynamic content in a page?

`Resumen.js`:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/Resumen/Resumen.html', {
    ready: function () {
        //Evento agregar nueva tarea
        document.querySelector('#agregar-tarea').addEventListener('click', irTarea, false);

        if (!LBR.registros_nuevos.es_primer_tarea) {
            agregarTarea();
        }
    }
});

function irTarea() {
    WinJS.Navigation.navigate('../pages/Tarea/Tarea.html');
}

function agregarTarea() {
    var reg = LBR.registros_nuevos,
        lista = document.getElementById('tareas-agregadas'),
        li = document.createElement('li');

    document.getElementById('resumen').className = '';

    li.innerHTML = '<div><h1>' + reg.tarea.descripcion + '</h1><p>' + reg.tarea.id + '</p></div>';
    li.innerHTML += '<div><h1>' + reg.articulo.descripcion + '</h1></p>' + reg.articulo.id + '</p></div>';
    li.innerHTML += '<div>' + reg.articulo.cantidad + '</div>';
    lista.appendChild(li);
}
```

`Tarea.js`:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/Tarea/Tarea.html', {
    ready: function () {
        //Mostrar el boton 'Atras'
        document.getElementById('atras').className = '';
        //Eventos de los buscadores
        document.getElementById('tarea-buscar').onkeyup = buscarTarea;
        document.getElementById('articulo-buscar').onkeyup = buscarArticulo;
        //Evento botón agregar
        document.getElementById('agregar').onclick = agregarTarea;
        //Evento botón atrás
        document.getElementById('atras').addEventListener('click', irAtras, false);
    }
});
function agregarTarea() {
    var tarea = {
        tarea: document.getElementById('tarea-seleccionada').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText,
        item: document.getElementById('articulo-seleccionado').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText,
        cantidad: parseFloat(document.getElementById('cantidad').value),
        item_udm: 'GL',
        mod_usr: 'jjlopez'
    },
        reg = LBR.registros_nuevos;

    reg.tarea.id = document.getElementById('tarea-seleccionada').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
    reg.tarea.descripcion = document.getElementById('tarea-seleccionada').getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText;
    reg.articulo.id = document.getElementById('articulo-seleccionado').getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
    reg.articulo.descripcion = document.getElementById('articulo-seleccionado').getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText;
    reg.articulo.cantidad = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cantidad').value);

    if (reg.es_primer_tarea) {
        reg.agregados[reg.indice_registros] = {
            nodriza: reg.nodriza,
            equipo: reg.equipo.id,
            odometro: 0,
            odometro_udm: 'KM',
            observaciones: 'Ninguna',
            creado_usr: reg.usuario.creado,
            mod_usr: reg.usuario.mod,
            fecha_apunte: new Date().getTime(),
            tareas: []
        }
    }
    reg.agregados[reg.indice_registros].tareas[reg.indice_tareas] = tarea;
    reg.es_primer_tarea = false;
    WinJS.Navigation.navigate('../pages/Resumen/Resumen.html');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Page navigation" in WinJS is a DOM-replacement mechanism, where in anything you have within the PageControlNavigator element (usually defined in default.html) gets replaced wholly with each navigation. Thus anything you add dynamically to one page will be dumped from the DOM when you nav away, and you'd have to restore it again when you navigate back.

One strategy around this is to not really navigate at all, but to just hide the previous page behind the new one on nav forward, so that nav back just hides or removes the second page so the first one becomes visible again.

Alternately, to preserve a block of the DOM across navigations, you'll need to temporarily move the root div of that content out from within the PageControlNavigator when you switch away from the page, and then re-parent it when you navigate back.

You could build a generic/automated mechanism with something like this:

- Have a hidden div in default.html, call it "Holder1" (you could have multiple such holders if you needed this behavior across multiple pages).
- Have a div in Resumen.html where you'll create your dynamic content, and mark it with something like data-holder="Holder1"
- Modify navigator.js (which is in your project) so that the _navigating function checks the DOM in the page being navigated away from for any element with a data-holder attribute, and re-parents its children to the indicated holder element (the attribute value). At the same time, add a data-target attribute to this holder in default.html to contain the id of the page element that contained those children.
- Similarly, in _navigating or _navigated, check if the page you're navigating to has an empty element with a data-holder attribute. If so, then take the children of that holder element in default.html and re-parent the contents into the new page once it's loaded up. (This is where you'd need unique holders for multiple pages.)